# Android TV banner small on device but correct on emulator

Tags: android-tv

I'm trying to upgrade my app to Android TV 8.0. When I run it in the emulator the banner for the app displays correctly, but when I run it on a Xiaomi Mi Box 3 the banner icon is cut off and is centered in the launcher. I've made sure the image is the recommended size, and I've set the android:banner on both the application and the activity to point to the correct drawable. Anybody have any ideas why it displays correctly in the Emulator. The Target SDK is set to 27 if that makes any difference.

Here is the application element in the Manifest.  The image is stored in the xhdpi drawable folder.

```
    <application
  android:name=".SerenityApplication"
  android:allowBackup="true"
  android:banner="@drawable/serenity_androidtv_banner"
  android:logo="@drawable/serenity_androidtv_banner"
  android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
  android:icon="@drawable/serenity_bonsai_logo"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:largeHeap="true"
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

Answer (score 2):

This is now working after a restart of the Xiaomi MiBox 3 device.  There appears to be a bug in the launcher after a fresh install of the latest update.  A restart of the device and it correctly loaded the banner for the app.